# WordPress REST API not enabled on new account

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Based on a quick research, WordPress REST API should be enabled after v4.7 (https://v2.wp-api.org/), however, I cannot access the REST API for my existing or new user by simply appending `{name}.wordpress.com/wp-json`, ie. https://steventsaotest.wordpress.com/wp-json does not return the expected JSON. Whereas sites like `http://www.tribunemedia.com/wp-json` works exactly as I wish, as well as my WordPress instance on Digital Ocean.

How can a user whose blog is registered with wordpress.com enable their REST API?

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    $namespace = 'aroma_api';
    register_rest_route( $namespace, '/get_signin', array (
        'methods'       => 'POST',
        'callback'      => 'get_singnin_data',
    ));
} );
function get_singnin_data($data)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $resultdata = array();
    $resultdata['message'] = 'Login SuccessFull';
    return $resultdata;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Where should I placed this piece of code?

Comment: This code is placed in function.php
or 
create new plugin for rest api and this code put in new plugin file.